# Numerical or analytical or exisistence: Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, laplace-transform, contour-integration

---

### Edit 1:

With the hint of Ron, we can simplify the question to :

$$\bar{f}(s)=\frac{1}{(s^2+1)\arctan s }$$

So what about this function's inverse Laplace Transform? Or can anyone tell me that the inverse transform is nonexist?

---

So the function is $$\bar{f}(s)=\frac{4\Omega}{(\pi-2\arctan\frac{2\Omega}{s})(s^2+4\Omega^2)}$$
with $\Omega>0$. I am expecting an ocillating function of angular frequency $2\Omega$ in the asymptotic form.

Using the Bromwich contour, I can find that we have a pole of first order at $s=0$. Two branch points $s=\pm 2i\Omega$, two poles also at $\pm 2i\Omega$.

I've got that $\mathrm{Res}f(0)=1$, and I've defined that the branch cut to be $(2i\Omega,i\infty)$ and $(-2i\Omega,-i\infty)$. However during the calculation I found there is divergence I don't know how to handle.

Is there any tool that can do this numerically, for example, set $\Omega=1$ and obtain a numerical result.

Comment: 1) The denominator may be simplified to $\arctan{[s/(2 \Omega)]} (s^2+4 \Omega^2)$.  2) You have a coinciding branch point and pole.  This is certainly doable, but the residue theorem is no help here.  Such situations can be complicated.  See, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162884/calculating-inverse-laplace-transform-of-stretched-exponential/1170635#1170635

Comment: @RonGordon I have the contour with two branch cuts, and a residual at zero. The problem is that I don't know hou to integrate along the branch cuts. The big arc and the small circle are zero. I've read that answer before, still couldn't work out this one

Comment: Yes, sorry, you do have a pole at zero.  If I get some time, I will try to outline how to do the integral around the branch cuts.

Comment: @RonGordon I've even calculate the contour along the branch cut, it seems zero. However I am not sure.

Comment: If there's a branch point, the integrals along the cut will not vanish.  Then again, there are two branch cuts and maybe in this case the integrals could cancel globally.  I very much doubt this is the case here.

Comment: @RonGordon Intuitively I couldn't believe all the integral along the contour will be zero, cause if that the case, the inverse transform will be identically the residual at zero, which is 1. However the laplace transform of 1 is $1/s$. This lead to the contraydiction.

Comment: @RonGordon Can you look at my answer to see if it has any flaws?when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a partial answer to my question.
The inverse fourier transformation can be obtained using the [Bromwich integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BromwichIntegral.html):

$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \frac{e^{st}}{(s^2+1)\arctan s } \mathrm{d}s$$

Define $g(s)$ for writing convenience:

$$g(s)=\frac{e^{st}}{(s^2+1)\arctan s } $$

To integrate this, we choose a contour as below:

[image]

Note that we have a pole at the origin and two branch points at $\pm i$.

Using this contour, we can apply cauchy theorem:
$$\mathrm{Res}g(0)=f(t)+\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\oint_{c_1}+\cdots\oint_{c_4}+\oint_\Gamma+\oint_{\gamma_1}+\oint_{\gamma_2})g(s)\mathrm{d}s$$

- We can easily get $\mathrm{Res}g(0)=1$.
- Using [Jordan's lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordansLemma.html), we have $\oint_\Gamma=0$
- For the contour $\gamma_1$, note that $s=i+\varepsilon e^{i\phi}$, with $\varepsilon\to 0$ and $\phi\in (\pi/2,-3\pi/2)$. So:

$$\oint_{\gamma_1}g(s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{-\frac{3\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{(i+\varepsilon e^{i\phi})t}\mathrm{d}\phi}{2\arctan(i+\varepsilon e^{i\phi})}\to 0$$
because $\arctan i \to \infty$. Similarly $\oint_{\gamma_2}\to 0$.

- So we are left with the contour $c_1\cdots c_4$.

## Integration along $c_1\cdots c_4$:

Because we have the branch cuts, we need only to consider the [principal value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalValue.html) of $\arctan$. The principal value is denoted as the first letter to be capital.

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Arctan}(z)=&\frac{1}{2i}\left[\mathrm{Ln}(1+iz)-\mathrm{Ln}(1+iz)\right] \\
=& \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Ln}\left|\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right| +\frac{\pi}{2},& \text{if $z$ on $c_1$and $c_4$}, \text{ i.e.,when $x\to 0^+$ and $|y|>1$} \\
    \frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Ln}\left|\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right| -\frac{\pi}{2},& \text{if $z$ on $c_2$and $c_3$}, \text{ i.e.,when $x\to 0^-$ and $|y|>1$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

So:

- $\oint_{c_1}$
  $$\oint_{c_1}g(s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_{+\infty}^{1}\frac{ie^{iyt}\mathrm{d}y}{(1-y^2)(\left(\frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Ln}\left|\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right|+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
- $\oint_{c_2}$
  $$\oint_{c_2}g(s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{ie^{iyt}\mathrm{d}y}{(1-y^2)(\left(\frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Ln}\left|\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right|-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
- $\oint_{c_3}$
  $$\oint_{c_3}g(s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{ie^{iyt}\mathrm{d}y}{(1-y^2)(\left(\frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Ln}\left|\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right|-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
- $\oint_{c_4}$
  $$\oint_{c_4}g(s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_{-1}^{-\infty}\frac{ie^{iyt}\mathrm{d}y}{(1-y^2)(\left(\frac{1}{2i}\mathrm{Ln}\left|\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right|+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$
- sum up: 
  $$\oint_{c_1}+\cdots+\oint_{c_4}=2\pi i \int_1^\infty \frac{4\cos xt}{(x^2-1)\left[\left(\ln\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|\right)^2+\pi^2\right]}\mathrm{d}x$$
  Where I've change the principal value $\mathrm{Ln}$ to the normal $\ln$, because the argument is positive real, we have no confusion about which branch we are using. i.e. we are back to the real argument integral.

## The asymptotic form of the above integration?

Now the whole problem is how can we get the asymptotic form of the above integral. Does it even exist? If exist, what form it takes when $t$ is very large? I've post this question to a seperate post:
[How to get the asymptotic form of this oscilatting integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315869/how-to-get-the-asymptotic-form-of-this-oscilatting-integral)