# How to find the Inverse Laplace of $\mathcal{L}^{-1} [ e^{-a [\Gamma(1-b)]^{1/2} s^{b/2}} {s^{-c}}] $

Tags: exponential-function, laplace-transform

The function in question

$fs1=exp(-a [Gamma(1-b)]^{1/2}  s^{b/2}) $

$ fs2=exp(-a [Gamma(1-b)]^{1/2}  s^{b/2})/(s^{b/2})$

$fs3=exp(-a [Gamma(1-b)]^{1/2}  s^{b/2})/(s^b)$

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} [e^{-a  [Gamma(1-b)]^{1/2}  s^{b}}  {s^{-c}}] $$

where $a>0$ , $0<b<1$ and $c>0$.

It need transform s to t.

How to find the Inverse Laplace ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162884/calculating-inverse-laplace-transform-of-stretched-exponential?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all we can use the '[convolution theorem][1]' of the [Laplace transform][2]:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(t\right):=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\cdot\text{s}^\text{p}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{s}^\text{p}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\tag1$$

Using:

- The '[time shifting][1]' property of the [Laplace transform][2]:

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\right]_{\left(x\right)}=\theta\left(x+\text{n}\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\right]_{\left(x+\text{n}\right)}\tag2$$

- Using the '[Table of selected Laplace transforms][3]':

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{s}^\text{p}\right]_{\left(x\right)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{p}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{x^{1+\text{p}}}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\theta\left(t+\text{n}\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\right]_{\left(t+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{p}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(t-\tau\right)^{1+\text{p}}}\space\text{d}\tau=$$

$$\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\right]_{\left(t+\text{n}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{p}\right)}\cdot\frac{\theta\left(t+\text{n}\right)}{\left(t-\tau\right)^{1+\text{p}}}\space\text{d}\tau\tag4$$

Now, using the series for $\exp$ we can write:

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\text{s}^\text{m}\right)\right]_{\left(t+\text{n}\right)}=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\sum_{\beta=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\text{s}^\text{m}\right)^\beta}{\beta!}\right]_{\left(t+\text{n}\right)}=\sum_{\beta=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\beta!}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{s}^{\beta\text{m}}\right]_{\left(t+\text{n}\right)}\tag5$$

Using the '[Table of selected Laplace transforms][3]':

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{s}^{\beta\text{m}}\right]_{\left(t+\text{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\beta\text{m}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(t+\text{n}\right)^{1+\beta\text{m}}}\tag6$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\left\{\sum_{\beta=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\beta!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\beta\text{m}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\left(t+\text{n}\right)^{1+\beta\text{m}}}\right\}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{p}\right)}\cdot\frac{\theta\left(t+\text{n}\right)}{\left(t-\tau\right)^{1+\text{p}}}\space\text{d}\tau=$$

$$\sum_{\beta=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\beta!}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\beta\text{m}\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(-\text{p}\right)}\int_0^t\frac{1}{\left(t+\text{n}\right)^{1+\beta\text{m}}}\cdot\frac{\theta\left(t+\text{n}\right)}{\left(t-\tau\right)^{1+\text{p}}}\space\text{d}\tau\tag7$$

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems

[2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

[3]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms